# WordPress / PHP 'Trying to get property 'feeds' of non object when trying to upload image from remote url

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to scrape some JSON data (that part works fine), but when I try and add the featured image, (a blank icon appears in the media library, with correct filename, but the url field says 'false' & I get this error:-

> Notice: Trying to get property 'feeds' of non-object in
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/post.php on line
> 4482
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> using_permalinks() on null in
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/link-template.php:423
> Stack trace: #0
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/link-template.php(147):
> get_attachment_link(Object(WP_Post), false) #1
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/post.php(4105):
> get_permalink(Object(WP_Post)) #2
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/post.php(5740):
> wp_insert_post(Array, false) #3
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446)
> : eval()'d code(92): wp_insert_attachment(Array, '/Users/macbook/...',
> 293) #4
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(446):
> eval() #5
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(534):
> execute_snippet('ini_set('displa...', 6) #6
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287):
> execute_active_snippets('') #7 /Users/ma in
> /Users/macbook/Documents/www/news_test/wp-includes/link-template.php
> on line 423 There has been a critical error on your website. Please
> check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Here's the code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
global $wpdb;

$json = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ie&apiKey=**************";
$response = file_get_contents($json);
$mydecode = json_decode($response, true);
$mydecode = $mydecode['articles'];

// error_log(printf($mydecode));


foreach ($mydecode as $key => $value) {
    
    $title = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $value['title']);
     $content = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $value['content']);
    //error_log("LOG: " . $title[0]);
    
   // $description = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $mydecode.articles->description);
   // $article_url = $mydecode.articles->url;
    $image_url = $value['urlToImage'];
   // $content = $mydecode.content;
    
 

            // Insert post
            $new_post = array(
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => $content,
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_category' => array(2),
                'post_type' => 'post'   
            );
            // Insert post
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
            // Insert post meta if available  
         //   add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );  

    // Add Featured Image to Post
// Add Featured Image to Post
  //  $image_url        = $urlToImage; // Define the image URL here
    //now to try and get actual image name
    $headers = wp_get_http_headers( $image_url );
$mime_type = $headers['content-type'];
$ext = '';
foreach ( wp_get_mime_types() as $exts => $mime ) {
    if ( $mime == $mime_type ) {
        $ext = $exts;
        break;
    }
}
    //now to apply extension if it didn't have one
    if( $ext ){
    $exts = explode('|', $ext);
    $ext = '.'.$exts[0];
}
    
    $image_name       = 'image';
    $upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
    $image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
    $unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name . $ext ); // Generate unique name
    $filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name

    error_log("Filenames: ".$filename);
    
    // Check folder permission and define file location
    if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    } else {
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    }

    error_log("file: ".$file);
    
    // Create the image  file on the server
    file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

    // Check image file type
    $wp_filetype = $exts[0];

    // Set attachment data
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
        'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    // Create the attachment
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

    // Include image.php
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    // Define attachment metadata
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

    // Assign metadata to attachment
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    // And finally assign featured image to post
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

I'm working on WordPress 5.5, and using the snippets plugin to execute the code.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

This is happening because you are calling `wp_update_post` too early in WordPress lifecycle. Hook your update logic to `init` and you will be fine.

**Long story**

This warning is coming from WordPress trying to find a pretty slug for the post, but being unable to do so because the Permalink logic has not loaded yet.

The warning comes from this line: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L4776

As you can see, the `$wp_permalink` global is populated kinda late in the lifecycle, AFTER `plugins_loaded` and before `init`: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L473-L479

So if you call `wp_update_post` on a plugin without a hook, the permalink global will not be populated yet.

So you should change your code flow to make sure it only runs `wp_update_post` after `init` has fired.